# Switch visibility between two divs

Tags: javascript, css, html, toggle

I want to switch/toggle visibility between div id1 and div id2.  I want div id2 to display by default when the page loads and when I click on a link I want div id1 to replace div id2.  I have tried a few different methods, even played around with it on jsfiddle a bit but I can't figure out what I am missing here.

HTML:

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility(id1, id2);">Change Payment Method</a>
<div id="id1" style="display: none"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2"><p>test 2</p></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) {  
var e = document.getElementById(id1);
var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
if(e.style.display == 'block') {                
  e.style.display = 'block';             
  e2.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
  e.style.display = 'none';            
  e2.style.display = 'block';
}              
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Look at the function signature:

```
function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) 
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Look how you are calling it:

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('id'); toggle_visibility('id2');"
                           ^^^^                     ^^^^^
```

Do they match? No. You want one call with two arguments

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');"
```

The other issue is your function is wrong, see Fibbe's solution for that

Comment: Yes, I see that, minor typo, but regardless, it doesn't work even when I corrected that.

Comment: That was not a minor typo. Fibbe's solution shows your other typo.

Comment: Because what are the variables id1 and id2? Look at what I did and what you did. You are missing the quotes around the strings.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use brackets in order to have multiple lines affected by the if-statement:

```
function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) {  
   var e = document.getElementById(id1);
   var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
   if(e.style.display == 'block') {                
      e.style.display = 'block';             
      e2.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
      e.style.display = 'none';            
      e2.style.display = 'block';
   }              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have wrongly written the statements qithin "if" and "else" in javascript function. The correct way is-

```
function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) {  
   var e = document.getElementById(id1);
   var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
   if(e.style.display == 'block') {                
      e.style.display = 'block';             
      e2.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
      e.style.display = 'none';            
      e2.style.display = 'block';
   }              
}
```

Also, you have passed the arguments in wrong way, the correct way is-

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');">Change Payment Method</a>
<div id="id1" style="display: none"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2"><p>test 2</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful:

```
<div id="mydivon" style="display:block">This is on.</div>
<div id="mydivoff" style="display:none">This is off.</div>


<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('mydiv');">Toggle Div Visibility</a>

<script language="javascript">
  function toggleDiv(divid)
  {

    varon = divid + 'on';
    varoff = divid + 'off';

    if(document.getElementById(varon).style.display == 'block')
    {
    document.getElementById(varon).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(varoff).style.display = 'block';
    }

    else
    {  
    document.getElementById(varoff).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(varon).style.display = 'block'
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u can use Jquery:

**Html**

```
<a id="button" >Click</a>
<div class="div show">1</div>
<div class="div">2</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('.div').toggleClass('show');
});
```

**Css**

```
.div {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
```

Comment: I really like this method, but I am attempting it on jsfiddle and it just doesn't work for me.  I have copied this verbatim.

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEzbC/) work example. I just think u forgot enable jQuery=)

Comment: @Arringar1 You would have to use jQuery. Are you? Your question is not tagged with the library.

Comment: First line in my answer is "If u can use Jquery:"

Comment: I did forget to enable jquery.  Unfortunately on the site I am using jQuery 1.4.4 which is as far as I can go without some major redesign. It does work on jsfiddle with 1.6.4 but it's not working for me on 1.4.4.  :(

Comment: I update jQuery on my [gsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEzbC/1/)  now it works with 1.10.1, it works with all jQuery version on fidle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');">Change Payment Method</a>
<div id="id1" style="display: none"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2"><p>test 2</p></div>
```

Comment: use below links, its working fine----->http://codepen.io/rohitKumar/pen/VYwmdj?editors=101